# How does Auto-Layout resolve constraints internally?

Tags: uikit, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, appkit

***IMPORTANT:** I know how to use Auto-Layout. How to use it has been asked before already and this is not a duplicate of that question.*

Auto-Layout is Apple’s cross-platform constraint-based layout system. But how does it resolve constraints? How does it know where views should be and how does it detect ambiguity?

## *How does Apple’s constraint solver work?*

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you could expect here? Auto-layout evaluates the constraints you've set (along with their Priority values)... it evaluates intrinsic content size when constraints are not set (or when set to `<=` / `>=` / etc)... it evaluates Content Compression Resistance / Content Hugging priorities... and so on. If it cannot satisfy all constraints - such as requiring a width of 500 when there is only 300-points available, or setting width to both 200 and 300 - it breaks (ignores) one or more of them.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already done a lot of research... if this article [Anatomy of a Constraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html) doesn't provide the information you're looking for, come back and ask *specific* questions.